# Represent visually a vector of index - R

Tags: r, vector, plot

I have a "logical" vector of `N` components like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 ...
```

I want to show a vector/matrix where the elements are colors. The element `i` is one color if the element `i` of my logical value is a 0 and another color otherwise. It's for representing a logical vector in a visual way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your expected output is, but maybe something like:

```
x <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(14L, 
    1L))

image(x, col = grey.colors(start = 1, end = 0, n = 2))
```

To give:

[image]

*Edit:* A nicer version:

```
z <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(14L, 
                                                                     1L))
x <- 1:nrow(z)
y <- 1:ncol(z)
image(x, y, z, col = grey.colors(start = 1, end = 0, n = 2), yaxt = "n", xaxs = "r")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use your logical vector in a `col=` argument for plotting, and the logical will be coerced into numeric.  So you could do

```
logi_vec <- sample(c(T,F), 20, replace=T)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

x <- rnorm(20)

# simple plotting, the pch=16 produces a solid dot
plot(x, col=logi_vec+1, pch=16)  # black vs. red

plot(x, col=logi_vec+2, pch=16)  # red vs. green

plot(x, col=2*(logi_vec+1), pch=16)  # red vs. blue
```

etc.

Note that this will work exactly the same way with a vector of 0/1 as with FALSE/TRUE.

If you want to see which colors correspond with which numbers on your machine, check out

```
palette()
# [1] "black"   "red"     "green3"  "blue"    "cyan"    "magenta" "yellow"  "gray"
```

So on my machine, a color of value 1 is black, 2 is red, etc.  Check out `?palette` to see how to change the default values.